# Must I enable the root account to install Matlab?

Tags: installation, root, matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab R20112a on Ubuntu.

My problem is: I get access to the installation gui running `./install` from a terminal, but the installer fails when it tries to write on the folder `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a` (even though I created this folder before running the installation).

I assume the problem is I need root privileges, but "root" is disabled in ubuntu.

I can install the program in my home folder, but this is not a good solution because I want access to the program for all users.

Answer (score 8):

[As explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), you do not need to enable root logins to *run commands as root*. That's what [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) and its graphical frontends (like [`gksu`/`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html) and [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html)) are for.

Since `install` runs a graphical installer, and you can run it (but not as root) like `./install`, you can run it as root with:

```
gksu ./install
```

Comment: Also, you can disable root login via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and prevent remote login through your root user.

Comment: @earthmeLon It should be disabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by default already (even when the root account is permitted to log in locally or via `su` with a password), as that is the default in Ubuntu and, I think, every other OS with sshd. Of course, anyone who *does* choose [to enable the root account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account) would still be well-advised to check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to *make sure* it remains disabled there.

Comment: My experience is different, @EliahKagan.  I just recommend being 100% sure root isn't exposed to sshd.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `gksudo ./install` from the terminal. This will run the install as root.

Comment: If `install` is graphical, it [should be run with a graphical frontend like `gksu` rather than directly with `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).

Comment: IIRC it's a CLI start followed by fall-forward to GUI by JRE if an X server is detected...

Comment: @izx Sounds like `gksu` is the way to go, then (as the X server will still be detected even if it's run with straight `sudo`).

Comment: Right-o, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the gksudo method but nothing happened.

Here's what worked for me: Download and install `furius.iso`, then mount the ISO.
Open the mounted image, and copy the installer's filename into the terminal. Then, type "./install" and when it asks you where to install, change it to `/home/your_user`, `~/` or so. Tested on 15.04.